# How to override class in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using Spring security rest plugin to authenticate the user. In this, there is a class named `RestAuthenticationFilter`. Now I want to call the methods of some custom class say `CustomRestAuthenticationFilter` (which extends `RestAuthenticationFilter`)  instead of `RestAuthenticationFilter`. How to do this?

Is there any way that we define in `resources.groovy` or somewhere else that to use `CustomRestAuthenticationFilter` instead of `RestAuthenticationFilter` ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the filtering is nicely described ... in the documentation!

https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/filters.html

Just amend the `grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames`value in the `Config.groovy` file so it contains your `RestAuthenticationFilter` instead of `RestAuthenticationFilter` and you should be good to go.